# 'Pass' password manager - does it require public key?

Tags: password, gpg

The 'pass' password manager uses gpg keys.

http://www.passwordstore.org/

However, gpg itself can be used for symmetric encryption of files.
Does pass only work using public/private keys, or is it possible to use with symmetric encryption?

Comment: `pass` just store(output, change, generate new ones, etc.) your text passwords in encripted storage in *key:value* form secured by *master-pass*. To receive some stored pass you should call `pass` with `key` and input *master-pass* for decription.

Comment: "To receive some stored pass you should call 'pass' with 'key' and input _master-pass_ for decription."  -- I'm afraid I don't understand. Could you give an example?

Comment: For example you have stored some pass with key `private_mail` (to list stored keys call `pass` without args). When you execute `pass private_mail` you'll be prompted to enter *master-pass* and if it true outputs the *pass* for `private_mail`

Comment: I think it can only use a pair of keys. Why would you prefer symmetric encryption ?

Comment: @Costas: I see, but then public key encryption is being used under the hood, so far as I understand.

Comment: @Leiaz: No special reason, just trying to understand how it works.

Comment: @Costas the "master-pass" is the passphrase of your gpg key. That's why you only have to input it when you retrieve the password, not when you store it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pass` password manager requires a public key for encrypting its files (where the managed passwords are stored) - and it requires a private key to decrypt its files.

It isn't possible to configure `pass` to use gpg's 'pure' symmetric file encryption (cf. the `-c` or `--symmetric` GPG options).

This is due to the design of `pass` - using GPG's public key cryptography for file encryption/decryption allows for flexibility, e.g. for configuring multiple keys - say - such that a group of users has access to the managed passwords.

Also note that GPG uses a hybrid scheme when encrypting a file for one or many recipients (i.e. using one or many public keys): it randomly generates a session key for the symmetric encryption of the file and then just uses the public key/keys to encrypt the session key.